# How to import Stata labels into R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently trying to export data from Stata to excel R. Everything works as expected except for Variables with a label are imported.

Is there a way to import the variables in such a way that R recognizes the label?

[image]

Sample data

```
structure(list(sn1 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = " point number  ", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    wjob12s5 = structure(c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = " day 5/ twelfth job line starts at  ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(` 4:01 4:15 ` = 1, 
    ` 4:16 4:30 ` = 2, ` 4:31 4:45 ` = 3, ` 4:46 5:00 ` = 4, 
    ` 5:01 5:15 ` = 5, ` 5:16 5:30 ` = 6, ` 5:31 5:45 ` = 7, 
    ` 5:46 6:00 ` = 8, ` 6:01 6:15 ` = 9, ` 6:16 6:30 ` = 10, 
    ` 6:31 6:45 ` = 11, ` 6:46 7:00 ` = 12, ` 7:01 7:15 ` = 13, 
    ` 7:16 7:30 ` = 14, ` 7:31 7:45 ` = 15, ` 7:46 8:00 ` = 16, 
    ` 8:01 8:15 ` = 17, ` 8:16 8:30 ` = 18, ` 8:31 8:45 ` = 19, 
    ` 8:46 9:00 ` = 20, ` 9:01 9:15 ` = 21, ` 9:16 9:30 ` = 22, 
    ` 9:31 9:45 ` = 23, ` 9:46 10:00 ` = 24, ` 10:01 10:15 ` = 25, 
    ` 10:16 10:30 ` = 26, ` 10:31 10:45 ` = 27, ` 10:46 11:00 ` = 28, 
    ` 11:01 11:15 ` = 29, ` 11:16 11:30 ` = 30, ` 11:31 11:45 ` = 31, 
    ` 11:46 12:00 ` = 32, ` 12:01 12:15 ` = 33, ` 12:16 12:30 ` = 34, 
    ` 12:31 12:45 ` = 35, ` 12:46 13:00 ` = 36, ` 13:01 13:15 ` = 37, 
    ` 13:16 13:30 ` = 38, ` 13:31 13:45 ` = 39, ` 13:46 14:00 ` = 40, 
    ` 14:01 14:15 ` = 41, ` 14:16 14:30 ` = 42, ` 14:31 14:45 ` = 43, 
    ` 14:46 15:00 ` = 44, ` 15:01 15:15 ` = 45, ` 15:16 15:30 ` = 46, 
    ` 15:31 15:45 ` = 47, ` 15:46 16:00 ` = 48, ` 16:01 16:15 ` = 49, 
    ` 16:16 16:30 ` = 50, ` 16:31 16:45 ` = 51, ` 16:46 17:00 ` = 52, 
    ` 17:01 17:15 ` = 53, ` 17:16 17:30 ` = 54, ` 17:31 17:45 ` = 55, 
    ` 17:46 18:00 ` = 56, ` 18:01 18:15 ` = 57, ` 18:16 18:30 ` = 58, 
    ` 18:31 18:45 ` = 59, ` 18:46 19:00 ` = 60, ` 19:01 19:15 ` = 61, 
    ` 19:16 19:30 ` = 62, ` 19:31 19:45 ` = 63, ` 19:46 20:00 ` = 64, 
    ` 20:01 20:15 ` = 65, ` 20:16 20:30 ` = 66, ` 20:31 20:45 ` = 67, 
    ` 20:46 21:00 ` = 68, ` 21:01 21:15 ` = 69, ` 21:16 21:30 ` = 70, 
    ` 21:31 21:45 ` = 71, ` 21:46 22:00 ` = 72, ` 22:01 22:15 ` = 73, 
    ` 22:16 22:30 ` = 74, ` 22:31 22:45 ` = 75, ` 22:46 23:00 ` = 76, 
    ` 23:01 23:15 ` = 77, ` 23:16 23:30 ` = 78, ` 23:31 23:45 ` = 79, 
    ` 23:46 0:00 ` = 80, ` 0:01 0:15 ` = 81, ` 0:16 0:30 ` = 82, 
    ` 0:31 0:45 ` = 83, ` 0:46 1:00 ` = 84, ` 1:01 1:15 ` = 85, 
    ` 1:16 1:30 ` = 86, ` 1:31 1:45 ` = 87, ` 1:46 2:00 ` = 88, 
    ` 2:01 2:15 ` = 89, ` 2:16 2:30 ` = 90, ` 2:31 2:45 ` = 91, 
    ` 2:46 3:00 ` = 92, ` 3:01 3:15 ` = 93, ` 3:16 3:30 ` = 94, 
    ` 3:31 3:45 ` = 95, ` 3:46 4:00 ` = 96), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: how are you trying to export the data? i'm not familiar with stata, but with sas you can create variable labels in a sas7bdat file and import that into r with `haven::read_sas`, have you tried something similar with `haven::read_dta`?

Comment: @rawr tried the haven::read_dta but it does not do the job